# Whether simple_html_dom.php uses cURL?

Tags: php, dom, curl, simple-html-dom

i want to know whether simple_html_dom.php  (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) uses cURL or not. I have a website in which i am using simple_html_dom.php to fetch data, my current hosting provider have enabled simple_html_dom.php  when i asked for. But now i want to change my hosting provider because of some economical reason. I have found another webhosting provider which allows curl functions (shown in their website); i called them and asked but they told they are not sure of simple_html_dom.php because no one has asked before. can you tell me whether simple_html_dom.php can be used in a cURL enabled server or not?.

Please forgive me if i asked a wrong questions..i have never done dom programming..i am using simple_html_dom.php  because its easy and i dont have to worry about dom.

Advance thanks for your help

Comment: If it isn't explained in the documentation, you can just fetch the source code and search for `curl` in your favourite text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course you can use [Simple HTML Dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) on cURL enabled server. The two are totally different things. Example:

```
$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://????????');  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);  
$str = curl_exec($curl);  
curl_close($curl);  

$html= str_get_html($str);
```